# Front end empty (i.e. nothing displays); Back end looks fine; What are possible causes?

Tags: errors, debug

My customer's site was working last night. Today nothing displays from the front end. Firebug gives  as the contents of the home page. I logged in. The back end looks fine. The most recent post (added yesterday some time) is there. I looked (briefly) at index.php, wp-blogheader.php, wp-config.php. They all look right at first glance. No obvious problem like the file being deleted or contents munged or the like. I looked at the database with phpmyadmin. The obvious options (home, etc.) look ok. The numbers of pages and posts etc. look OK. Which is consistent with the back end looking right.

Running WP 2.9.2 and Semio Reloaded 0.9.2, Version Checker 2.1.5 active. All plugins updated according to version checker.

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Possible clue based on "what did you do recently?"... I deleted an old (2.8.?) WP install from a different directory/folder. The deleted install was in /news2/. The current one is served from /news/. The databases for both installs were in the same MySQL db. The old deleted one had "wp_" as the table prefix. The current one has "asepco_" as the table prefix. Again, a look at the db using phpmyadmin shows that both sets of data are there, and nothing obvious seems amiss.

Any "did you look at ..." type suggestions would be welcome. I'm a bit stumped right now.

-Denny

Comment: do this first: http://wpmu.org/daily-tip-enable-wordpress-debugging-for-efficient-plugin-development

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the default theme? Does that work?
Did you change the wp-content folder to something else?

Comment: Good idea. Switch to default theme fixed the problem. Switching back to original theme retained the fix. I found the answer on Wordpress.org at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-install-old-database-blank-front-page?replies=3

Comment: **@xsace** If that fixed your problem, please select this as "the" answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is quite an old post, but thought of giving a possible solution, which worked out for me.
Go to the root of your wordpress installation and open up index.php and replace following code.

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

with,

```
require('wp-blog-header.php');
```

Since, I'm hosting on windows server, ./ resembles filename on current directory in linux environment.